# create relation between all pairs sharing common property, avoid self-cycle

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with a property, say "from". I want to create a mutual link based on this property. When I do so with my code, it also creates self-relationships and I want to avoid this. 
Any idea?
Thanks.

```
CREATE (c:User { name: "Cristopher", from: "france"})
CREATE (m:User { name: "Marc", from: "france"})
```

Then

```
MATCH (u:User { from: 'france' }),(v:User { from: 'france' })
CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[r:FRENCH]->(v)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure u and v are not the same node before you create the relationship.

```
MATCH (u:User { from: 'france' }),(v:User { from: 'france' })
WHERE u <> v
CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[r:FRENCH]->(v)
```